# Trigger in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo-3.x

My Requirement is as follows:
In below table code  if records gets inserted into "col" I should do some manipulations to "col2" table, How to achieve this? is my below code correct, I am trying to see what insert_change prints, but it is not printing anything

```
import pymongo
import logging
import Parameters,constants  

class Stream:
    def get_connection(self):
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(
            "mongodb://" + constants.USER_NAME + ":" + constants.PWD + constants.server + constants.CA_CERTIFICATES_PATH)
        logging.info("Mongo DB Connection Established Sucessfully")
        db = client[Parameters.STG_QC_Hub_Files]
        col = db[Parameters.col7]
        col2 = db[Parameters.col8]
        return col,col2,db

    def insert(self,col,col2,db):
        try:
            with db.col.watch([{'$match': {'operationType': 'insert'}}]) as stream:
                print(stream)
                for insert_change in stream:
                    print("hi")
                    print(insert_change)
                       
                    
        except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError:
            # The ChangeStream encountered an unrecoverable error or the
            # resume attempt failed to recreate the cursor.
            logging.error('...')
c=Stream()
col,col2,db=c.get_connection()
c.insert(col,col2,db)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will print what you have inserted into the table:

```
import pymongo
import logging
import Parameters,constants,mongotriggers
from bson.json_util import dumps


class Stream:
    def get_connection(self):
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(
            "mongodb://" + constants.USER_NAME + ":" + constants.PWD + constants.server + constants.CA_CERTIFICATES_PATH)
        logging.info("Mongo DB Connection Established Sucessfully")
        db = client[Parameters.QC_Quality_Hub]
        col = db[Parameters.col7]
        col2 = db[Parameters.col8]
        return col,col2,db

    def insert(self,col,col2,db):
            try:
                resume_token = None
                pipeline = [{"$match": {"operationType": "insert"}}]
                a = [doc for doc in col.find({})]

                with  col.watch(pipeline) as stream:
                    print(stream)
                    for insert_change in stream:
                        print(dumps(insert_change))
            except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError:
                logging.error("Oops")
c=Stream()
col,col2,db=c.get_connection()
c.insert(col,col2,db)
```